# Change Text Size Of TabLayout Design Library with ViewPager not Works

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

There is TabLayout And View Pager
After Setup View Pager :

MainActivity.java :

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    viewPager.setAdapter(null);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), getString(R.string.fragment_one_title));
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), getString(R.string.fragment_two_title));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

activity.XML :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.emaarit.app.nikanco.activities.ServicesActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"/>
    <TextView
        android:background="@color/toolbar_red_line_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_red_line_height"/>
    <include layout="@layout/layout_title_bar"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/service_tab_unselected_text_color"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabLayoutTextAppearance"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        android:background="@color/service_tab_background_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

style.xml :

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabText</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/service_tab_selected_text_color</item>
</style>
<style name="MyCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_content_title</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

It shows Tabs with `default Size`, And dont Change Underline Color of Tabs !
How I Can Fix It

I started With Here[this Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) And want to change It.

Comment: app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar it not works

Comment: remove  style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout" and check once